# How to fix 'Could not resolve com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.8.' error in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, classpath

Sync error in my project and i'm getting **Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.8.** error and sync failed in android studio.

To solve this error i'm adding the dependency in my build.gradle file from https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3718

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
         jcenter()
    }
}
dependencies {
     implementation 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.8'
}
```

For solving this error what should i do ??

Comment: You probably added it in the wrong build.gradle file

Comment: Add ``implementation 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.8'`` in the app/build.gradle file

Comment: i'm check it again. it's added app/build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you go to

**File** -> **Settings** -> **Build,Execution,Deployment** -> **Gradle** -> then deselect **Offline Mode**....if it's selected....

This should work

Then add `implementation 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.8'` in your build.gradle file

And I also suggest you Migrate to **AndroidX**:

To do that go to **Refactor** -> **Migrate to AndroidX** -> **Migrate**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.8'
}
```

If you're using the **Support Library** you need to downgrade the library version.

Check [this](https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker) for more info

I hope this helps...